# asp:ValidationSummary in div elemenet and styled

Tags: asp.net, css, validation, html

```
<div style="width:100%; background-color:Aqua; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; height:30px;">
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" HeaderText="Error" />
</div>
```

i dont want to show div element if has no error . i dont want to use js, just with asp controls !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `height:auto; line-height:30px;` instead of `height:30px;`

```
<div style="width:100%; background-color:Aqua; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; height:auto; line-height:30px;">
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" HeaderText="Fill" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create new webcontrol and derive it from ValidationSummary and override Render method, so to wrap your real ValidationSummary with div just like you want.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output) {
   writer.Write("<div class=\"validationsummary-wrap\">");

   //Write the derived validation summary
   base.Render(writer);

   writer.Write("</div>");
}
```